# org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException for create a tag

Tags: svn, exception, tags, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have a problem since I installed Tortoise comes with VisualSVN for Visual Studio.
From eclipse I can not create TAG.
I have the following error message.

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: File not found: revision 392, path '/InitGabaritExcel/trunc/InitGabaritExcel/trunc'
svn: '/repository_svn/!svn/bc/392/InitGabaritExcel/trunc' path not found: 404 Not Found (https://xxxxx)
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: File not found: revision 392, path '/InitGabaritExcel/trunc/InitGabaritExcel/trunc'
svn: '/repository_svn/!svn/bc/392/InitGabaritExcel/trunc' path not found: 404 Not Found (https://xxxx)
```

Indeed, the path `InitGabaritExcel/trunc/InitGabaritExcel/trunc` does not exist.
The right path is `InitGabaritExcel/trunc`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `trunk` not `trunc`:

```
https://xxxxx//repository_svn/InitGabaritExcel/trunk/InitGabaritExcel/trunk
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
The directory name is trunc (error made ​​by the operator).
Before installing tortoise everything worked perfectly.

Comment: I solved my problem.
The mistake was that I migrated server and I passed under svn 1.7.3.
My version of subclipse 1.6 was not compatible.
I switched to version 1.8 and subclipse I updated my projects and everything is back to normal.

Comment: then this answer it is not correct. place your own answer, and check it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Eclipse (Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)) and Subclipse 1.8.x, while creating a new branch from the trunk.
It was resolved when I upgraded my subclipse version to 1.10.13. Both Eclipse and Subclipse need to be compatible.